# How do I loop through a Python list of hrefs with Selenium to get a webelement in each href?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to be able to visit a list of hrefs and in each link, find a Webelement associated with a CSS selector:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/a[@class='card-info']")

links = []
for elem in elements:
    links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
links
```

This gets me the list of hrefs fine. I then try to loop through the hrefs by clicking on each link, finding the Webelement by CSS selector and appending it to an empty list:

```
for link in elements:
    link.click()
    year = []
    year.append(driver.find_element_by_class_name('year-info'))
```

This does not work and I receive the following error: `"NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".year-info"}"`

I've only been writing in Python for a week so I apologize for any glaring syntax errors. I'd appreciate any guidance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through Links using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803259/looping-through-links-using-selenium)

Comment: for link in links:?